# Using Ebay API with Angular & Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ebay-api

I am having issues with using the Ebay API with my Angular application. What I'm doing is getting data back from Ebay which is in the form of JSON. This is all fine but I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _cb_findItemsByKeywords is not defined
```

See my TypeScript code below:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { url } from 'inspector';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-web-scrape',
  templateUrl: './web-scrape.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./web-scrape.component.css']
})
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebScrapeComponent implements OnInit {

  _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
    var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
    var html = [];
    html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
      var item     = items[i];
      var title    = item.title;
      var pic      = item.galleryURL;
      var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
      if (null != title && null != viewitem) {
        html.push('<tr><td>' + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="0">' + '</td>' +
        '<td><a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></td></tr>');
      }
    }
    html.push('</tbody></table>');
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");
  }  // End _cb_findItemsByKeywords() function

  ngOnInit() {
    var url = "https://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
    url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
    url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=ConorRaf-TheEazyT-PRD-d55b8f6ea-a1f297a5";
    url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
    url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
    url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
    url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
    url += "&keywords=harry%20potter";
    url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=3";
    console.log("hello from ts");
    var s=document.createElement('script'); // create script element
    s.src = url;
    console.log(s.src)
    document.body.appendChild(s);

  }
}
```

The code compiles fine, and returns some sort of JSON objects, but I get this error within the console:

[image]

The error seems to be within the callback:

[image]

HTML just for reference:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>eBay Search Results</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>eBay Search Results</h1>
<div id="results"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where did you call _cb_findItemsByKeywords method?

Comment: Its called within the string ‘url’. It is appended to the string.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using this `script` thing? You should rather stick to the Angular way and use the [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) service.

Your code would look like:

```js
this.http.get(url).subscribe(root => _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root));
```

instead of adding the request in a `script` tag.

You can first get a feeling of how it works with a simple:

```
this.http.get(url).subscribe(root => console.log(root));
```

and build the logic from there.

And by the way, the Angular way is not to manipulate DOM directly like you do. Much of the power of Angular comes from templating and data binding. I advise you to explore the [Angular doc](https://angular.io/guide/architecture) to get a good grasp of what is going on when you use Angular.

Comment: May be problem come from CORS from eBay

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I use the http.get, I get a CORS issue. Any workaround you know about?

Comment: No, you must use the ebay API as intended, if they open some calls. CORS means that the ebay server blocks your call because you are not one of their own sites. So either they have a public API you can use (I don't know), or you cannot do what you want. That's a security protection on their part (in short: to protect from someone who would embed calls to their API from their own website without the user knowing. Look up cross scripting attacks to know more).

Answer (score 0):

Yes as said above you shouldn't be using script with angular. It goes against the principals of the language. I would highly suggest checking out the [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/docs) to gain a better understanding of how to use components.

Also I presume you are a beginner so another good resource for novice programmers is available at [Tutorialspoint Angular](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular6/angular6_overview.htm)

Comment: Thanks again, I'v been at this for ages and have been banging my head over this and I'v begin using HttpClient, but I keep running into the CORS issue. Is it possible to get around this by using Angular and TypeScript alone? Or do I need to use a backend server for this? Can't seem to find a straightforward answer anywhere.

Comment: Yes i would highly recommend using a backend server, use your server for generating the data and use angular just for displaying.